# Difference between ending iOS app from xcode and from recent list

Tags: ios

Is there a difference between ending an iOS app from xcode and ending it explicitly(manually) from recent list of backgrounded apps?

The reason I ask is this: In some places in Apple's documentation (like for Push Notifications) they mention that an app has to be explicitly ended in order for certain things to be reset.

Comment: when you _stop_ the application form the Xcode, the application will be terminated suddenly skipping the standard termination protocol. (the app won't get any notifications, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases a `SIGKILL` signal is sent to the app's process to kill it, so there should be no difference.

Comment: Thanks, wonder if that's the reason it does not get removed from the recents list when ended from xcode?

Comment: The answer is in the question itself: those are recently opened applications, not the active ones.